# JavaScript Functional Programming - Nested Loops

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

Lets say I have an `Array` of `Object`s and each have an `Array` of objects inside them.

```
let nestedObjects = [{
  name: '1',
  values: [{id: 1}]
},
{
  name: '2',
  values: [{id: 2}]
}]
```

Now, I want to do something with each `Object`'s `values id`. Sort of like this

```js
let nestedObjects = [{
    name: '1',
    values: [{
      id: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    values: [{
      id: 2
    }]
  }
];

let someArray = [];
nestedObjects.forEach(obj => {
  obj.values.forEach(value => {
    someArray.push(value.id * 2);
  });
});

console.log('Values', someArray);
```

I can sort of change this to use a `reduce` and possibly a `map` inside the reduce, but it still feels clunky and not really "functionally". Is there a different way to write it to make it shorter and easier to read?

I would like to get to something like:

```
let someArray = nestedObjects.map(obj => obj.values)
.map(value => value.id * 2)

console.log('VALUES', someArray);
```

*Note:* It is not really about the above code, but more about the FP way of thinking/coding.

Comment: Why don't you want a map inside a reduce? `nestedObjects.reduce((p, o) => p.concat(o.values.map(v => v.id * 2)), [])` looks tidy enough.

Comment: This is similar to the solution I was going to present

Comment: @Ozan looks good enough, true. Just curious as to a potentially better way of writing it, and why. Not so much about "good enough" or getting the code to work, but more of a FP discovery mission for myself. Yes, there are resources out there about FP in JS, but sometimes it's hard to apply it to a specific situation, like this one (for me at least).

Thanks for the responses though :)

Comment: You need a `reduce` inside a `map`, because the latter have to return the same context, that is an `Array` in your example: `nestedObjects.map(o => o.values.reduce((acc, p) => acc + p.id * 2, 0))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and spread to flatten the subarrays to a single array. Then iterate the results with the 2nd map:

```js
const nestedObjects = [{"name":"1","values":[{"id":1}]},{"name":"2","values":[{"id":2}]}];

const someArray = [].concat(...nestedObjects.map(obj => obj.values))
.map(value => value.id * 2);

console.log('VALUES', someArray);
```

The combination of getting an array from a property, and flattening the result is called `flatMap`, so you can extract the code to a method:

```
const flatMap = (cb, arr = []) => [].concat(...arr.map(obj => cb(obj)));
```

**Important note:** the spread argument is not stack-safe, this `flatMap` method will fail for a huge amount of data.

**Demo:**

```js
const nestedObjects = [{"name":"1","values":[{"id":1}]},{"name":"2","values":[{"id":2}]}];

const flatMap = (cb, arr = []) => [].concat(...arr.map(obj => cb(obj)));

const someArray = flatMap(({values}) => values, nestedObjects).map(value => value.id * 2);

console.log('VALUES', someArray);
```

btw - Native JS [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/) is a [stage2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#stage-2), and it should probably make it to the language in ES2018 or ES2019.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial instinct to use reduce/map is good – your worry that it's not "functional" is unfounded; it's functional – it uses functions, produces no side effects, and will always produce the same result given the same initial input

```js
const data0 =
  [ { name: 1, values: [ { id: 1 } ] },
    { name: 2, values: [ { id: 2 } ] } ]

const data1 =
  data0.reduce ((acc, { values = [] }) =>
    acc.concat (values.map (v => v.id)), [])
  
console.log (data1)
```

You can drop the default `= []` if you're guaranteed that each item in `data0` will have a `values` property with an array value

---

This reducing/flattening of an array is common, and can be abstracted for easier reuse – another user provided something similar but it included a fatal flaw which could result overflowing the stack – this implementation avoids that problem

```js
const concatMap = (f, xs) =>
  xs.reduce ((acc, x) =>
    acc.concat (f (x)), [])

const data0 =
  [ { name: 1, values: [ { id: 1 } ] },
    { name: 2, values: [ { id: 2 } ] } ]

const data1 =
  concatMap (({ values = [] }) =>
    values.map (v => v.id), data0)

console.log (data1)
```